# I am trying to make a batch that call two subbatchs depending on a response. It does not working properly

Tags: batch-file

[This is the code, sorry is my first question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvJqX.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code inside, rather than linking to a picture. You will get a better response that way. Also state what exactly is not working - are you getting an error message or some other behaviour

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question. (Use the edit button)

Answer (score 0):

[I think you'll get better responses by copying in the code here instead of showing a picture of it]

Your call to the subroutine is
    Call :TestCom2
and the subroutine starts with a label
    :TestCom2
and ends with
    GoTo :EOF

Denis

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a batch file containing a subroutine.

```
prompt $g

set fred="a b c d e f g"
call :TestSub1 %fred%
call :TestSub2 %fred%
GoTo EndBatch

:TestSub1
echo %1
Pause in TestSub1
GoTo :eof

:TestSub2
echo %~1
Pause in TestSub2
GoTo :eof

:EndBatch
Pause at EndBatch
```